# how i print strings in implode function

Tags: php, mysql

`$color` is array

```
$sql=" SELECT * FROM products  WHERE color IN (".implode(',', $color).")";
```

its showing result is

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE color IN (red,green,blue);
SELECT * FROM products WHERE color IN ('red','green','blue');
```

Comment: Use it as `'".implode("','", $color)."';`//  output 'red','green','blue'

Answer (score 4):

Update your query like as

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM products  WHERE color IN ('".implode("','", $color)."')";
                                           //^^         ^^  ^^          ^^ Added
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products  WHERE color IN ('".implode("','", $color)."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use It like this:

```
 $sql = "select * from products  where color IN ('".implode("','", $color)."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

While using `'` around implode and `"','"` as a glue works like a charm in this situation you can also use `array_map` to surround each value of the array with `'` and then implode with simple `,`

```
$color = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
$string = implode(
    ',',
    array_map(
        function ($value) {
            return "'{$value}'";
        },
        $color
    )
);
echo $string; // => 'red','green','blue'
```

It might be overkill in this case and it may be a little slower than other answers.